# Missing intercepts of OLS Regression models in Python statsmodels

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am running a rolling for example of 100 window `OLS regression estimation` of the dataset found in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUMVFyYTEtWXlzYkk) (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2Iv8dfU4fTUMVFyYTEtWXlzYkk) as in the following format.

```
 time     X   Y
0.000543  0  10
0.000575  0  10
0.041324  1  10
0.041331  2  10
0.041336  3  10
0.04134   4  10
  ...
9.987735  55 239
9.987739  56 239
9.987744  57 239
9.987749  58 239
9.987938  59 239
```

The third column (Y) in my dataset is my true value - that's what I wanted to predict (estimate). I want to do a prediction of `Y` (i.e. predict the current value of `Y` according to the previous 3 rolling values of `X`. For this, I have the following `python` script work using `statsmodels`.

```
# /usr/bin/python -tt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm


df=pd.read_csv('estimated_pred.csv')    
df=df.dropna() # to drop nans in case there are any
window = 100
#print(df.index) # to print index
df['a']=None #constant
df['b1']=None #beta1
df['b2']=None #beta2
for i in range(window,len(df)):
    temp=df.iloc[i-window:i,:]
    RollOLS=sm.OLS(temp.loc[:,'Y'],sm.add_constant(temp.loc[:,['time','X']], has_constant = 'add')).fit()
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('a')]=RollOLS.params[0]
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('b1')]=RollOLS.params[1]
    df.iloc[i,df.columns.get_loc('b2')]=RollOLS.params[2]

# Predicted values in a row
 df['predicted']=df['a'].shift(1)+df['b1'].shift(1)*df['time']+df['b2'].shift(1)*df['X']

#print(df['predicted'])

print(temp)
```

Which gives me a sample output of the following format.

```
         time   X   Y        a           b1           b2  predicted
0    0.000543   0  10     None         None         None       NaN
1    0.000575   0  10     None         None         None       NaN
2    0.041324   1  10     None         None         None       NaN
3    0.041331   2  10     None         None         None       NaN
4    0.041336   3  10     None         None         None       NaN
..        ...  ..  ..      ...          ...          ...       ...
50    0.041340   4  10       10            0  1.55431e-15       NaN
51    0.041345   5  10       10   1.7053e-13  7.77156e-16        10
52    0.041350   6  10       10  1.74623e-09 -7.99361e-15        10
53    0.041354   7  10       10  6.98492e-10 -6.21725e-15        10
..        ...  ..  ..      ...          ...          ...       ...
509  0.160835  38  20       20  4.88944e-09 -1.15463e-14        20
510  0.160839  39  20       20  1.86265e-09  5.32907e-15        20
..        ...  ..  ..      ...          ...          ...       ...
```

Finally, I want to include the mean squared error (`MSE`) for all the prediction (a summary of the `OLS` regression analysis) values. For example, if we look at row 5, the value of `X` is 2 and the value of `Y` is 10. Let's say the prediction value of `y` at the current row is 6 and therefore the `mse` will be `(10-6)^2`. The `sm.OLS` returns an instance of this class `<class 'statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS'>` when we do `print (RollOLS.summary())`.

```
OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      Y   R-squared:                        -inf
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                   -inf
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    -48.50
Date:                Tue, 04 Jul 2017   Prob (F-statistic):               1.00
Time:                        22:19:18   Log-Likelihood:                 2359.7
No. Observations:                 100   AIC:                            -4713.
Df Residuals:                      97   BIC:                            -4706.
Df Model:                           2                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const        239.0000   2.58e-09   9.26e+10      0.000       239.000   239.000
time        4.547e-13   2.58e-10      0.002      0.999     -5.12e-10  5.13e-10
X          -3.886e-16    1.1e-13     -0.004      0.997     -2.19e-13  2.19e-13
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       44.322   Durbin-Watson:                   0.000
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               86.471
Skew:                          -1.886   Prob(JB):                     1.67e-19
Kurtosis:                       5.556   Cond. No.                     9.72e+04
==============================================================================
```

But the value of `rsquared`(`print (RollOLS.rsquared))`, for example, should have been between `0` and `1` instead of `-inf` and this seems to be the issue with `missing intercepts`. If we want to print the `mse`, we do `print (RollOLS.mse_model)`... etc as per the [documentation](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html). How can we add the `intercepts` and print the regression statistics with the correct values as we do for the predicted values? What am I doing wrong in here? Or is there another way of doing this using `scikit-learn`libraries?

Comment: Visualizing the data from @FLab's answer i might suggest trying to regress the differences in Y on X + a constant (which will be your average change per unit time). if you are trying to predict Y though for arbitrary times fwd this could be difficult because you would not have all the intermediate Xs necessarily... a bit difficult to give a better answer than that without a specific use case/goal

Comment: How would we regress the differences in `Y` on X? I actually have found out that if you set the `intercept` to `False`: `model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=df.Y, x=df[['X']], 
                               window_type='rolling', window=3, intercept=False)` - it gives better values (for example: `R-squared: 0.5999`). Do you know how we can turn `intercept` to `False` in `statsmodels`?

Comment: instead of `sm.OLS(temp.loc[:,'Y'],sm.add_constant(temp.loc[:,['time','X']], has_constant = 'add')).fit()` just use `sm.OLS(temp.loc[:,'Y'],temp.loc[:,['time','X']).fit()` to take differences you can say `df['Y']=df.diff()['Y'].values`. also do not confuse getting a value for Rsq and inf as "better". I agree with @Flabs that OLS on levels is probably a poor model (depending on your use though). hence why i suggested differencing your dependent variable because to me it looks like there is an underlying growth rate + noise correlated to X (maybe even changes in X)

Comment: If we do `RollOLS=sm.OLS(temp.loc[:,'Y'],temp.loc[:,['time','X']]).fit()`, we will have the error `IndexError: index out of bounds`. And when do `df['Y']=df.diff()['Y'].values`, we have an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`.

Comment: For the first problem you have to remove the saving of the constant since it now does not exist in the parameters. For your second problem it is because when you diff() a dataframe of course your first value becomes a `nan` as there is nothing to difference, so you can do `df.dropna()` or run only on `df.iloc[1:,:]`

Comment: Very strange but I don't know why we get `IndexError: index out of bounds` error when we remove the constant. I am still getting that error. It is the same error we had last time if you could remember. To solve the error we had last time, I had to add `has_constant = 'add'`.

Comment: might have to do with your version of statsmodels. maybe try `has_constant=False`, although I'm not sure. you may have to check the documentation on that one.

Comment: It should be `has_constant = 'skip'` according to the documentation but that doesn't seem help either. I will try to install the latest version of `statsmodels` and see if that helps.

Comment: I installed the latest version of `statsmodel: 0.8.0` and the error is still there. By the way, when we regress the difference in `Y` on `X` - the values of `Y` becomes `0.00` on almost all of the rows. I think i will be better of to stick with `OLS` instead.

Comment: Yes, because you are now predicting the change in Y, not Y itself (it is still OLS though). I might suggest reading up on linear regressions and first differencing. Introductory econometrics by Wooldridge is a favorite of mine, but just use google and there are plenty of free lecture slides on it. Wikipedia is also a decent resource in a pinch, although perhaps dives into the math more than practical explanation than you might want.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

The value of `r^2` is going to be `+/- inf` as long as `y` remains constant over the regression window (100 observations in your case). You can find more details below, but intuition is that `r^2` is the proportion of `y`'s variance explained by `X`: if `y`'s variance is zero, `r^2` is simply not well defined.

*Possible solution:* Try to use a longer window, or [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) Y and X so that Y does not remain constant for so many consecutive observations.

**Long Answer**

Looking at this I honestly think this is not the right dataset for the regression.
This is a simple plot of the data:

[image]

Does a *linear* combination of X and time explain Y? Mmm...doesn't look plausible.
Y almost looks like a *discrete* variable, so you probably want to look at [logistic regressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

To come to your question, the R^2 is the "the proportion of the variance in the dependent variable that is predictable from the independent variable(s)".
From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination):

[image]

In your case it is very likely that Y is *constant* over 100 observations, hence it has 0 variance, that produces a division by zero hence the inf.

So I am afraid you should not look to fixes in the code, but you should rethink the problem and the way of fitting the data.

Comment: Aha, OK and thank you. The problem that I wanted to solve is predicting current value of `Y` (the ground truth) from the current (or some previous values - for example 10 windows) of `X`. I am not sure if we can do this using logistic regression. As you can see from my plot here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUTkt1akRpc2lXeW8 - I want to find the pattern of the pink plot against my ground truth (actual value). Do you think using logistic regression will help?

Comment: This is more a statistic question rather than a programming one. First, I would not use time as explanatory variable. You introduce time by doing a rolling regression (so everyday you recompute the estimation), but you are not saying that Y is a deterministic function of time. Second, by looking at the chart you probably want to use some moving average of X, to make it look more similar to Y.

Comment: I did that FLab. Even if I do a moving average of X so as to make it look similar to `Y`, I am still getting the same value for `rsquared` (`-inf`). I can share my code for the moving average as well if you want to look at it along with both my actual dataset and the estimated dataset.

Comment: @FLab A Logistic regression is mainly used to predict binary classification ( 1 - 0 are possible outcomes) I would use Poisson Regression that predicts counting.

Comment: @FLab,  I have now made an interpolation of estimated data (check `interpolated_data.csv`) and the plots look very much similar now. I have shared both the data and the new plot in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUR0d2VkNxQUdsYjg. However, when i do the regression, i still am getting `-inf` value for r^2. I would appreciate if you could have a look at it when you get a chance.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it clearer why you get r^2 = inf

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I prepared this small example so you can visualize what a Poisson regression could do.

```
import statsmodels as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
poi_model = sm.discrete.discrete_model.Poisson

x = np.random.uniform(0, 20,1000)
s = np.random.poisson( x*(0.5) , 1000)
plt.bar(x,s)
plt.show()
```

This generates random poisson counts.

Now the way to fit a poisson regression to the data is the following:

```
my_model = poi_model(endog=s, exog=x)
my_model = my_model.fit()
my_model.summary()
```

The summary displays a number of statistics but if you want to compute the mean square error you could do that like so:

```
preds = my_model.predict()
mse = np.mean(np.square(preds - s))
```

If you want to predict new values do the following:

```
my_model.predict(exog=new_value)
```